# Binding ListBox.SelectedItem to Property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox, selecteditem

This might be a duplicate question, but I'm unable to find a good answer. All the answers like [Binding WinForms ListBox to object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815828/binding-winforms-listbox-to-object-properties) don't work on my WinForm. I'll explain.

I have a list of Firms that I show in a `ListBox`. I would like when the SelectedItem changes, that it updates a property on my model. So that I can read the Firms properties.

```
// the classes
public class Firm
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // more properties ...
}

public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Firm _firm = new Firm();
    public Firm Firm
    {
        get { return _firm; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _firm)) return;
            _firm = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    // more properties and OnPropertyChanged() ...
}

// the form
private MyModel Model;

public void MyForm(List<Firm> firms)
{
    lstFirm.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", Model, "Firm",
        true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    lstFirm.DisplayMember = "Name";
    lstFirm.ValueMember = "Id";
    lstFirm.DataSource = firms;
}

public void lstFirm_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with Model.Firm
}
```

The problem is that `Model.Firm null` is. Does anybody have an idea what I need to do to make a databinding between the `ListBox` and the `Model`? I bind other stuff on my WinForm (such as `TextBoxes` to `String` properties) and those work nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a weekend of testing, I figured it out.

I was debuging in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and didn't see the change in my Model.Firm just yet. But as the `SelectedItemChanged` event is only internal, I couldn't use that and that's where the databinding on SelectedItem applies the values to databound items.

Now the reason why the change isn't visible yet, is because the `SelectedItemChanged` is only fired after the `SelectedIndexChanged` is executed. So internally in the `ListBox` control, it probably looks like

```
this.SelectedIndex = value;
this.SelectedItem = FindItem(value);
this.SelectedIndexChanged(/*values*/);
this.SelectedItemChanged(/*values*/); // Apply databinding changes
```

So it's quite normal that you don't see the changes, before the change has occured. And I didn't know this, so I was kinda stumped why the SelectedItem (who was displaying the changed value) wasn't copied over to the databound model property.

So I didn't have to change anything major to get it all working. :)

Comment: Still unclear what you changed...

Comment: I'm very sorry, I don't know anymore. My current self is sorry that my past self didn't provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, your code never sets Model.Firm...  Where's the constructor for MyModel?  If you don't provide one, Model.Firm will stay null unless you explicitly set it.  Here's an example constructor:

```
public MyModel(Firm firm)
{
    _firm = firm;
}
```

Also, `Equals()` doesn't do what you think it does.  Instead of `if (Equals(value, _firm)) return;`, use this: `if (value == _firm) return;`

Comment: private Firm _firm = new Firm(); is also a valid solution

Comment: I have added a default firm to my constructor and I have modified the setters. (Default Resharper implementation, didn't think about Equals vs comparer.) But allas, no luck.